# how to import and call same named functions from 2 folders in 1 project space in python?

Tags: python, python-import

how to [rename](https://www.lintcode.com/problem/3164/description?showListFe=true&page=1&problemTypeId=8&submissionStatus=TODO&pageSize=50) the imported file with the same name?

There are folders named branch1 and branch2 under PROJECT in our current work project, and there is a file with the same name solution.py in these two folders.

```
# Write your code here
from branch1 import do as a
from branch2 import do as b
# Keep the code below
a.do()
b.do() #but it's not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I have seen in your given link is-

You have two folders called `branch1` and `branch2`. Each of the folder has a file named `solution.py` and there is a `do` function inside that.

The problem statement tells you to import the `solution` files and rename them so that you can use them without collisions. If you see the code snippet, the key is in `a.do()` and `b.do()`. You are not importing do functions, but the solution files.

The problem you are having is in the line

```py
from branch1 import do as a
```

You are trying to import the function `do` as `a` directly. There is no `do.do()`. So they don't work. Based on your problem statement, the import statement should be-

```py
from branch1 import solution as a
from branch2 import solution as b

a.do()
b.do()
```

You will get an output like below if you run this-

```
We are running in branch/branch1.solution.py
We are running in branch/branch2.solution.py
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.do` was hint, implying that, you need to import a and then in that import there is a method/function do, which will execute.

```
# Write your code here
from branch1 import solution as a
from branch2 import solution as b

# Keep the code below
a.do()
b.do()
```